# How to make an empty cookie check

Tags: javascript, cookies, document, setcookie

I have a cartHelper:

```
let cartHelper = {
    cartCookieName: "_cart",

    getCart: function (callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.getRequest(
            "/carts",
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                if (callback) { callback(); }
            },
        )
    },
}
```

I want to call getCart function if "_cart" is empty. Can you help me with how I can make this check? More clearly, getCart function is being called when the button is clicked. And I am making and API call to get the cart_guid and I am storing in cookie. What I am trying to do if cart_guid is already in the cookie, I dont want to do anything but if it is not I want to create the cookie with cartguid.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="checkCookie()">Check Cookie</button>
    <p>Click btn to check cookie..!</p>
  </body>
  <script>
    function getCookie(name) {
      var dc = document.cookie;
      var prefix = name + "=";
      var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
      if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
      } else {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
          end = dc.length;
        }
      }
      // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
      //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
      return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    }

    function checkCookie() {
      var myCookie = getCookie("MyCookie");

      if (myCookie == null) {
        console.log(
          "%ccookie is null",
          "color:white;background: red;padding: 2px 10px;"
        );
      } else {
        console.log(
          "%ccookie is not null",
          "color:white;background: red;padding: 2px 10px;"
        );
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```